# Blurry text in a NSTextField

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1, blurry

I have a problem with NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask, the text gets blurry after I added it.

With NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask: http://cl.ly/image/2t0M1R201d1F

Without http://cl.ly/image/1o0K3d3s3t3j

Code:

```
self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;
self.window.movableByWindowBackground = YES;
self.window.styleMask = self.window.styleMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask;
```

Comment: Usually caused by half-pixel positioning. This is particularly likely to happen when positioning something by centering it. Make sure that your label has integer coordinates (preferably, integers that are even).

Comment: Label gets blurry with integer coordinates.